# Registering a protobuf schema with a WKT with Confluent kafka schema-registry

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

I am unable to figure out how to register a Protobuf schema using the well-known wrapper types (eg `Int32Value`) with Confluent's Schema Registry, due to what I believe is a missing reference.

As a minimal example, I defined the following schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message TestMessage {
  google.protobuf.Int32Value wrappedInt = 1;
}
```

Trying to register it results in an invalid schema error:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8081/subjects/test/versions?normalize=false -d '{"schemaType":"PROTOBUF","schema":"syntax = \"proto3\";\n\npackage test;\n\nimport \"google/protobuf/wrappers.proto\";\n\nmessage TestMessage {\ngoogle.protobuf.Int32Value wrappedInt = 1;"}'
{"error_code":42201,"message":"Invalid schema syntax = \"proto3\";\n\npackage test;\n\nimport \"google/protobuf/wrappers.proto\";\n\nmessage TestMessage {\ngoogle.protobuf.Int32Value wrappedInt = 1; with refs [] of type PROTOBUF"}
```

I presume the issue is the missing reference to the `Int32Value`. However, the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-protobuf.html#developer-notes) says:

> Do not upload Google/Protobuf dependencies into Schema Registry. Although you might naturally expect the tooling to automatically exclude any “dangerous” files which ought not be imported, this is not the case.

If I register the `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` subject, all is well. (I believe this is the equivalent of `skip.known.types=false` in the `ProtobufConverter` config, at least with auto registration enabled, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the section of the docs I quoted above.) How does one correctly register a schema using a WKT?